# How to extract only the outer tags using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to extract only the outer  tag.

```html
<tr><td class="tdstyle"><b>Sub Sub Category</b></td><td class="tdstyle" style="font-weight:bold">U/s.482 Cr.p.c under sec.138 and 142</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="4"><table class="B2U-article" style="width: 100%"><tbody><tr><td>IA Number</td><td>Filing Date</td><td>Advocate Name</td><td>Misc.Paper Type</td><td>Status</td><td>Prayer</td><td>Order Date</td><td>Order</td></tr><tr><td style="font-weight:bold">IA 1/2019</td><td style="font-weight:bold">19/07/2019</td><td style="font-weight:bold">J RAMMOHAN RAO</td><td style="font-weight:bold">Stay Petition</td><td style="font-weight:bold">Pending</td><td style="font-weight:bold"><a href="#" id="prayerlink" onclick="getPrayer(&quot;to stay the operation of the orders in CrI M P No 445/ 2019 in CrtANo 542/2019 On the file of the Court of XV Addl District and Sessions JudgecmXV Addl Metropolitan Sessions JudgecumII Addl Family Court, Ranga Reddy District at Kukatpally, for the offence punishable under section 138 of Negotiable Instruments Act, pending disposal of the above petition and pass&quot;)">IA PRAYER</a></td><td style="font-weight:bold">-</td><td></td></tr><tr style="color:green"><td style="font-weight:bold"> IASR 41174/2019</td><td style="font-weight:bold">18/07/2019</td><td style="font-weight:bold">J RAMMOHAN RAO (7615)</td><td style="font-weight:bold">Stay Petition</td><td style="font-weight:bold">PENDING FOR SCRUTINY</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>
```

```py
basic_table_row_tags = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[1]/tbody/tr')
```

By using the above code I am getting all the  tags.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by _outer tags_? What is your exact usecase?

Comment: Some tr tag contains a table inside. By running the above code I am getting tr tag which is inside parent tr tag. But I don't need the child tr tag I just want parent tr tag.

Answer (score 0):

Can u please try this: //table[1]/tbody/tr[1]
this will give u all the table headers
and to get specific header like "IA Number" you can use //table[1]/tbody/tr[1]//td[1] and so on.